# Sharing authentication in Django

Tags: django, cookies, angular

we are developing an application using Angular2 as frontend and Django as a backend. A Django backend is already in place, while the Angular2 application is in development. We chose, for obvious reasons, to use Django REST as a way to communicate with the backend.

The application login and the backend login are done in two different pages but of course the login domain and the user base is the same. The two login are working properly by themselves, but we wanted to find a way to implement a transparent login (so an user can log into any of the two application and be recognized by the other one without re-logging).

The Angular frontend is currently using Token Authentication. The server does send the csfr and session cookie along with the token. Moving to the backend, the csfr cookie is preserved, while the session is not, so a new login is required (of course, backend and Angular frontend are on different subdomains but in the same domain, the cookies are set on the domain, with two dots: '.domain.com') .
Is it possible to do what we desire? Could someone help us find the proper way to do it?
We've done some research and found Django CAS, but it's not clear for us what's about and if it fits our use case.

Thank you very much